# Overlap between vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two vector subspaces $U, V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\dim(U), \dim(V) < n$, is there a quantity that expresses the amount of "overlap" between the two spaces in a meaningful way? The quantity should increase when the overlaps between individual vectors from $U, V$ increase.

**EDIT, MORE DETAIL:**

Let us say that I know $U$ exactly; it is spanned by some eigenvectors of a matrix $M$ I have. However $M$ might be hard to diagonalize, so I try to approximate by some algorithm I have. This algorithm generates $V$, and I hope I will find the vectors that span $U$ in there, or vectors that have large overlaps with the aforementioned eigenvectors.

Let us for simplicity say that $U$ and $V$ have the same dimension, say, 4. By using the vectors in $V$ I find that the best overlaps I can get with the eigenvectors I'm seeking are 0.99, 0.98, 0.90, and 0.80. Overlap between vectors is the scaled inner product

$$\frac{\langle u | v \rangle^2}{\langle u | u \rangle \langle v | v \rangle}$$

In this case none of the overlaps are 1, so wouldn't that make the dimension of the intersection zero? If so then I need some other quantity than the one suggested by @JLinsta and @Aldoggen that somehow takes the overlaps above into consideration... If such a quantity exists :P

Comment: Maybe $\frac{dim(U \cap V)}{min\{dim(U),dim(V)\}}$?

Comment: It is still possible that the vectors don't fully overlap, but their spans do overlap, as when you take two different bases for the space $\mathbb R^4$. Can you confirm or deny that you seek a measure for the overlap of the vectors, and edit accordingly to get a properly defined question? If you seek a measure for the overlap of the vectors, why not take the norm of the vector composed by the individual overlaps you mentioned?

Comment: I really really don't understand what you mean by "vectors that have large overlaps with the aforementioned eigenvectors"; what does it mean for vectors to overlap?

Comment: @Aldoggen I'm seeking a measure that summarizes the four individual overlaps I chose as examples... A typical case for me is that $V$ contains a vector with very large overlap with one of the eigenvectors I use to span $U$, but the others are not so good, so the overall quality of my approximation is poor.

Comment: @MorganRodgers the overlap of two vectors is $\frac{\langle u | v \rangle^2}{\langle u | u \rangle \langle v | v \rangle}$.

Comment: The problem comes from quantum physics where a physical state is a ray in Hilbert space, so two vectors represent the same physical state if their overlap is 1.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I should point that that does not at all match up with what you say in the first sentence of your post: "quantity would be minimal (0) when the intersection of $U$, $V$ is $\{0\}$", since any two eigenvectors that don't have the same span will span spaces with trivial intersection regardless of their overlap.

Comment: That's a different notion of overlap I believe.

Comment: @MorganRodgers you are probably right, so maybe that property of the quantity I'm seeking must be forsaken.

Comment: @Aldoggen ok, maybe a more suitable description of what I'm after is this: given the definition of overlap between two vectors that I've written down, is there a suitable generalization of this to **sets of vectors** instead of single vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the new problem, I do not know of a generalization of individual overlaps, but a simple ad hoc solution exists: gather your overlaps into a vector $o=(0.99, 0.98, 0.90, 0.80)$, take the norm, and normalize with the norm of $(1,1,1,1)$. This normalized norm I will call the summary $s$. It is a number between 0 and 1, and increases as the individual overlaps increase.

You want the summary $s$ to only be close to 1 when all overlaps are close to 1, so you could take the $p$-norm

$$\lVert x\rVert_p = \left({\sum_{i=1}^k}x_i^p\right)^\frac1p$$

with $p$ a small number, for example $p=0.2$. If $p<1$ this formula is not actually a norm, but it's still useful. With $p=0.2$ and $o$ as above, we find $s\approx0.914$. I also made this [interactive desmos example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bazb2di1i6).

---

An alternative is to go with my answer for the original question: the intersection $W$ of $U$ and $V$ is again a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, so you could look at its dimension. If you want to scale this quantity, you can notice that the dimension of $W$ will be at most $\min(\dim U, \dim V)$, so you can divide by that to get the formula which JLinsta mentioned in the comments:
$$\frac{\dim W}{\min(\dim U, \dim V)}.$$

Even if none of the overlaps are 1, the approximating eigenvectors can still generate exactly the same vector space as the eigenvectors of $M$ itself, in which case the above quantity will be 1. For example, the real plane is generated by the standard basis, but also by the standard basis rotated by one degree.

Comment: Sorry, I think I need to be more specific in my question, this might be too course-grained for my needs (maybe). Please see my edit and thanks for answering!

Comment: Nice idea!! This might do the trick!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I would just take the product of the individual overlaps:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{\dim(U)} \langle u_i|v_i\rangle
\end{equation}

provided your vectors are normalized and $\dim(U) = \dim(V)$, and you're interested in a one-to-one comparison of the vectors.

If you want to compare the spaces spanned by the vectors, and not the vectors themselves, you can use the concept of [principal angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats), which can be easily obtained from the singular values of the matrix of inner products:

\begin{equation}
M_{ij} = \langle u_i | v_j \rangle
\end{equation}

The singular values are the cosines of the principal angles (there are $\min\left(\strut\dim(U),\dim(V)\right)$ of them, and at most $n-\min\left(\strut\dim(U),\dim(V)\right)$ are nonzero, so cosine $\ne 1$). Again, taking the product of the singular values gives you a single number that is $1$ if the subspaces are identical (or if one is a subspace of the other), and $0$ if there is at least one degree freedom in the smaller subspace that is completely orthogonal to any vector in the other subspace.